# Please suggest which method is correct to proceed

Tags: include, subfiles

I'm using the following tags to generate a project:

```
\documentclass{book}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\include{fm}
\mainmatter
\include{ch01}
...
\include{ch10}
\backmatter
\bibliographystyle{...}
\bibliography{...}
\printindent
\end{document}
```

This was produced the output in a nice manner, but today I saw some post regarding `\usepackage{subfiles}`, and the usage is:

```
\documentclass{book}


 \usepackage{subfiles}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\subfile{fm}
\mainmatter
\subfile{ch01}
...
\subfile{ch10}
\backmatter
\bibliographystyle{...}
\bibliography{...}
\printindent
\end{document}
```

This also working fine, and this is allowed to treat each chapter as separate compilation, i.e., we able to use `\documentclass...\end{document}` in each file, but the first method doesn't allow to run each chapter as separate file.

Kindly suggest which one is opt to use, please

I'm not an expert in `TeX`, so can't able to take decision, please advise.

Comment: `\include` is the standard latex command. `subfiles` is OK but is quite an invasive change as it has to change a lot of file handling, so you may get package conflicts. I would use  the standard system until you are used to that but feel free to experiment with alternatives

Comment: you can run separate files with `\include` by using `\includeonly{ch10}` this is good for quick editing when working on chapter 10. It formats a chapter10 not as a new document, which is better or worse depending on what you want

Comment: I'm the current maintainer of the `subfiles` package, and also suggest to avoid the `subfiles` package unless really needed, for the reason David gave. Personally, I usually use `\input` commands in the main file and comment/uncomment them as needed.

Comment: @gernot Much thanks for your honest comment, it helps me a lot

Comment: @gernot If possible, can you post your `comment` as `answer`, so that the future users will aware of that, thanks.

Comment: @GowriSaro My comment is not suitable as a general answer. To me it seemed that you did not have a particular use case requiring the `subfiles` package, so the recommendation is not to use it (as it potentially may have side-effects). Your question is not so specific that there is a clear-cut answer for other users as well. I know that there are quite some people out there who like to use `subfiles`.

Comment: @gernot OK, understood and thanks for your detailed explanation